# GNU readline History feature

Tags: c, unix, shell, readline

I'm using this code for the history features in my shell: 
http://cc.byexamples.com/20080613/gnu-readline-how-to-keep-a-history-list-of-entered-command-lines/
but when I compile this using gcc, I got this error

```
$ gcc filename.c
/tmp/ccay2CgM.o: In function `main':
rl.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `rl_abort'
rl.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `rl_bind_key'
rl.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `readline'
rl.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `add_history'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Comment: can you add the exact command you're using to compile it?

Answer (score 11):

The example compile line is

```
g++ -o simple_rl{,.cpp} -lreadline
```

Did you forget to add the -lreadline?

Comment: Just to add a little something here, take note that `-lreadline` must come after the source file that needs it on the command line. I spent way too much time learning that the hard way. ;)
See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html for why.

Comment: Shanet, Thank you so much, I'm just coming off of spending more time than I'm going to admit to myself finding out my I can't link readline. If you post the question to "why can't I link libreadline" I'll get all of my friends to upvote you.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with this:

```
gcc -lreadline -lncurses -o simple_rl{,.cpp}
```